# Regex Camel Case only first Uppercase by group

Tags: regex, pcre

This is my current regex:

`/([A-Z])(?![A-Z])/gm`

Bellow how it's evaluated:

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/K1gvmr/1

In the print you can see I'm getting:

**[F]** oo **[B]** ar XYBA **[Z]**

And instead I need to get that matches:

**[F]** oo **[B]** ar **[X]** YBAZ

How a negative lookahead (or another approach) can stop evaluation in the first char of each group only?

Comment: Have you explored all the possibilities? `FooBarXYBAZing A DDo` ?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Regex: `(?<![A-Z])[A-Z]`

Explanation:
A negative look behind for A-Z followed by any character in A-Z

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K1gvmr/2)